# How to track steps in a linear workflow

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a model for a Task in a workflow. The task has a `ManyToMany` field that allows users to add approvers who can approve each step in the task.

```
class Task(models.Model):
    approvers = models.ManyToManyField(
        get_user_model(),
        through='TaskStep'
    )
```

I am using an [OrderedModel](https://github.com/bfirsh/django-ordered-model) as an intermediary model to keep track of the order of each approval, with the intention to pass the Task linearly from one approver to the next as they sign off the Task:

```
class TaskStep(OrderedModel):

    approver = models.ForeignKey(
        get_user_model(), null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL
    )
    task = models.ForeignKey(Task, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    order_with_respect_to = 'task'
    status = models.BooleanField()
```

Assuming that each step is simply a True/False confirmation from each approver in the `approvers` field, what's the simplest way to keep track of which TaskStep the Task approval is on?

E.g. Do I add a field to `Task` like `Step` and try and turn the `approvers` ManyToMany field into a list via `__init__`?

**Use case example**:

- A user defines a task with 4 approvers listed in the ManyToMany field
- The order of those approvers is set via the OrderedModel.

  - E.g. Approver 1 --> Approver 2 --> Approver 3 --> Approver 4
- The workflow then passes the Task to each approver in turn along the order defined. The status of `TaskStep` is `False` for each approver until they confirm and it is set to `True`

**I need a way to track which step the Task is on so I can direct it to the appropriate approver (user).**

**Edit:**

*Specifically, I need a solution so that I can create a query for a given user that returns all tasks they are assigned as the current (active) step on. I thought the best way to do this may be to create a field in the Task model and update it to return the user associated with the step, but I am not sure how to do this.*

Comment: Since it is a M2M model, a `Task` can have zero, one or *more* `TaskStep`s.

Comment: Is there always (at most) one `TaskStep` for a `Task` where the `status` is `False`?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Correct, there can be zero, one or more than one approvers (task steps). All steps are False until they are approved and then the task is complete. Please see edit with Use case example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can obtain the *first* task for which `status=False` with:

```
next_step = TaskStep.objects.filter(task=my_task, status=False).first()
```

or through *`my_task`* itself:

```
my_task.taskstep_set.filter(status=False).first()
```

The `OrderedModel` has an `order` field, and orders by that field, so `.first()` will return the first one in the order. It will return `None` if no such `TaskStep` exists.

This `TaskStep` thus has a reference to the next approver that needs to approve.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to save this value against the model record itself? E.g. I would like to create an inbox for users who have active tasks, so would need to reverse lookup where they are the current step.

Comment: I was thinking, for example how could I run a query on a user to display all tasks where they are the current step (approver)?

Comment: @alias51: hmm... that's a harder problem. That will likely require a subquery.

Comment: Would it be better to create an `IntegerField` in `Task` for the step and then to set the current step / user on init somehow?